# How to do interactive notification on chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I am currently about to complete the development of a chrome plugin. I 'd like to know if there is a way to display notifications on the icon of the plugin , calling an external web service?

Here is a small example :
chrome plugin = > webservices calling => Webservices returns => icon number update

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK15T.png)

The following line of code displays notifications on the plugin tab

**chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "2+"});**

Anyone have an idea ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this and it works fine.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
setInterval(function() {
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "2"});
}, 3000);
});
```